# Cosmos DB not retrieving data for partition key

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azureportal

So I'm pretty sure I've always been able to do this before.
I'm debugging why my queries aren't returning data.  I thought perhaps my code wasn't actually creating the documents, but I can look up and find the documents with the c._self.
Then I realized that I can't even do this:

```
select top 1* from c where c.PartitionKey= 'Value'
```

Or just about anything else with my Partition Key included.
This seems backward..

Here's my indexing policy:

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/RecordStartDate/?",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "/meta/timestamp/?",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "/Table/?",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": []
}
```

Comment: You should be using the property you partitioned by, not "`PartitionKey`" (unless you actually have a property named "`PartitionKey"` - try using the actual name of the property and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Yes, I changed that because I don't want to share the actual property name.

Comment: Ah - sorry, didn't catch that nuance. So, I just tried re-creating your issue, and cannot: when I query within a partition key, I get data back (a single document in this case, given `top 1 *`. The index scheme shouldn't make a difference in this case, since you're not doing any property filtering (aside from partition key).

Comment: May I ask where you're executing this query?

Comment: In the portal.  The newer sql query view.

Comment: I get mixed results in the portal as well when it comes to partitioned collections. Can you do the same using the C# or the js SDKs?